# How can I create two users on ftp to reach different directories?

Tags: iis, ftp

How to create ftp account for 2nd user? I have the following scenario.

I have domain xxx.yyy.com. when user type in this it will ask for their username and password. This will direct them to folder C:\test\125. What I want now is create another user that goes to directory C:\test\150. I tried to create another user on test.yyy.com same domain. however it's not giving me any errors just not accepting the username and password. I can see on log file opens the session accepts the log in and closes the session again.

Now either I have xxx.yyy.com and depending on user goes to this directory C:\test\150 ou this C:\test\125. How can I do this?

or have this

test.yyy.com and goes to one directory C:\test\125.

How can I do this.

Thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 0):

in godaddy server it has option for give a access path when creating user for FTP accounts. by this you can solve issue